# how to create a custom slider with "slide to unlock" effect for iphone 5 in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create a custom slider with "slide to unlock" effect for iphone 5 in objective c with custom images.

Comment: that's great, let us know how you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout these controls. Are you looking like these?

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/slide-to-unlock

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mbsliderview

Comment: thanks tried all this ,but these does not work for iphone 5...

Comment: @megha — why are they not working for iPhone 5 and what stops you from making them to work?

Comment: Main thing that will affect you is the ARC. Just import these files into your project and set these files in NON-ARC format. It will work fine. i guess. Doesnot work means. Whats the problem you faced?